# Filtering a text file content in JAVA

Tags: java, text, filtering

I have a large txt file that content keyboard letters and some other unknown letters. I need to filter my txt file that only content keyboard keys. I am new to java, so i do not have an idea about how to do this. If anyone know a solution, please help me to complete this task. My expectation is that the code gets the file path and read the txt file and filter it and replace it. Just to clarify here is some content that the current txt file contents.

```
                      aš         @                3g     Ð ÃJ    q~Pøt  ½ïþ       @ð#    @ð#?                        &   €š         @                3m       ¾Ý ¤P@u  ½ïþ      @ð#   @ð#?                        "   ¦š         @                    d   C : \ P r o g r a m   F i l e s   ( x 8 6 ) \ M o z i l l a   F i r e f o x \ f i r e f o x . e x e   :   C : \ W i n d o w s \ S y s t e m 3 2
```

Comment: What do you mean with "I need to filter my txt file that only content keyboard keys"? Do you need to change the file and exclude the "non-keyboard characters"? or what do you mean with "filtering" it?

Comment: Do you need to do that in Java? If yes, then you're on the right track, i.e. read the file's content, remove the unwanted characters (replace using regular expressions) and then write the content back to some file. If no, then do the same but using command line tools like grep, cat etc. (which on windows should be provided by cygwin etc.)

Comment: yes i want to exclude the non-keyboard characters and the result txt will only contain keyboard characters. Please help me to do this.